# Proving Big Omega of a polynomial without limits

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

Here is the definition of $\Omega$:

> $f(n) = Ω(g(n))$ iff there exist positive constants $c$ and $n_0$ such that $f(n) \ge cg(n)$ for all $n\ge n_0$.

Here is one theorem:

> If $f(n) = a_m n^m + \cdots + a_1 n + a_0$ and $a_m > 0$, then $f(n) = \Omega(n^m)$.

I want to prove this, without using limits. Despite many hours of searching across the internet, all I could find is proofs using limits. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $M = \max(|a_0|/a_m, |a_1|/a_m, \ldots, |a_{m-1}|/a_m)$, and take $c = a_m/2$ and $n_0 = 2mM$.
Then for $n \geq n_0$,
$$
\begin{align*}
f(n) &= a_m n^m \left(1 + \frac{a_{m-1}}{a_m} \cdot \frac{1}{n} + \cdots + \frac{a_1}{a_m} \cdot \frac{1}{n^{m-1}} + \frac{a_0}{a_m} \cdot \frac{1}{n^m}\right) \\ &\geq
a_m n^m \left(1 - \frac{M}{n_0} - \cdots - \frac{M}{n_0^{m-1}} - \frac{M}{n_0^m}\right) \\ & \geq
a_m n^m \left(1 - \frac{mM}{n_0}\right) \\ &=
c n^m.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: I try another way, but it seems better. thanks.